# Changes to "Software and Updates " not saving

Tags: updates

Upgraded to 17.10 and I'm unable to make any changes to the settings in "Software and updates".  I can't check any boxes such as enabling Canonical Partners, or changing the updates to "long term support versions only".  It also does not prompt me for a password for elevated permissions.

I have tried creating another user account with Sudo permissions and experience the same results.  Any suggestions?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so as a last ditch attempt I decided to reinstall the desktop environment.  This was a relatively painless action (even for a non-techie) and seemed to do the trick.

"sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop"